# Minimization of regularized functional

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-optimization, locally-convex-spaces

**Background:**

Let $x,y$ be points in $\mathbb{R}^D$.  Let $C$ be functionals from $\mathbb{R}^D$ to $\mathbb{R}$, which are strictly convex and convex respectively.  Moreover, assume that $F$ is differntiable everywhere and $C$ is differentiable everywhere except at $0$.

Define the minimization problem:

$$
\underset{\gamma(0)=x,\gamma(1)=y,\gamma \in C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R}^D)}{\operatorname{argmin}}
 L(\gamma)=\int_a^b  \|\dot{\gamma}\|_2^2  + C(\dot\gamma(t))\,dt.
$$

I deduced that there exists a solution by convexity of the functional $L$ on the Banach space $C^1([0,1],\mathbb{R}^D)$, and it must be unqiue, since the sum of a convex and strictly convex functional.

**Question:**

How can I prove that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^n \gamma}{\partial t^n}(t) = 0; n\geq 2
.
\end{equation}

**Failsafe:**

*(If this is false what other requirements do I need to impose on $C$ to make it true, weaker than strict convexity)?*